# Mime / Base 64 encoding

Tags: php, delphi, base64, mime, encode

I need a way to encode a string to Mime/Base64 in Delphi 7 and PHP

These two encoders must be compatible :)

Comment: Who is going to encode, and who is going to decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit EncdDecd has been included since Delphi 6; below are the Mime compatible base64 functions it contains.

This [cached post from FlexVN](https://web.archive.org/web/20100724014328/http://www.flexvn.net/blog/uncategorized/encodedecode-base64-with-delphi-and-php.php) (the [original post](http://www.flexvn.net/blog/uncategorized/encodedecode-base64-with-delphi-and-php.php) is not always on-line) explains how to do the base64 thing between PHP and Delphi using the EncdDecd unit.

```
unit EncdDecd;

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils;

procedure EncodeStream(Input, Output: TStream);
procedure DecodeStream(Input, Output: TStream);
function  EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
function  DecodeString(const Input: string): string;

function  DecodeBase64(const Input: AnsiString): TBytes;
function  EncodeBase64(const Input: Pointer; Size: Integer): AnsiString;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Indy-Project](http://www.indyproject.org/) provides base64 encoder/decoder classes. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/IdCoderMIME_pas.html).

For PHP, you can use the PHP-internal functions [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) and [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/base64_decode).