# Simple MIME Base64 Decoder

Tags: delphi, email, base64, mime, thunderbird

I'm looking for an easy way that doesn't involve using something like Indy to just decode Base64 that contains what the message from Thunderbird said.

Example:

```
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
```

Becomes:
Your message

```
  To:      xxx@xxx.com
  Subject: Ixxx
  Sent:    Thu, 22 Oct 2009 01:14:34 -0400

did not reach the following recipient(s):

xxx@gxxx on Tue, 27 Oct 2009 01:40:44 -0400
    The e-mail system was unable to deliver the message, but did not
report a specific reason.  Check the address and try again.  If it still
fails, contact your system administrator.
    < Cinxxx.com #5.0.0 smtp; 5.4.7 - Delivery expired
(message too old) 'timeout' (delivery attempts: 0)>
```

Edit: Seems that the max length a MIME Base64 line can be is 76. I have to decode each 76 bit long line, not the entire message at once. Thanks.

Comment: I use the base64 code from madExcept. Maybe that's included in the free utilities that madshi distributes?

Comment: It is quite easy to write by yourself. Each 3 8 bit characters encoded as 4 6 bit one. Anyway, preloaded Indy have at least one decoder implementation.

Comment: The JEDI JCL has an implementation which I use. And my advice is never write code for yourself if you can access something which already does the job well and has been tested in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decoding isn't that hard to code up, but here's a blog with some sample code for Delphi

http://www.delphifaq.net/how-to-base-64-mime-encode-and-decode-a-string/

The basic idea is that there are 64 characters, each represent a bit pattern for 6 bits.  You turn the character back to its 6 bits with a table look-up, and then you take your list of bits, and break them back into 8-bit chunks to make bytes.

Comment: If your Delphi is an older ANSI Delphi (2007 or earlier) then you will need to replace `string` with `AnsiString` in the linked code.

Comment: This is very helpful, however when actually trying to use it, it only works if the length of the input string is a multiple of 4. That doesn't seem right, considering I have a string that isn't and decodes just fine using an online decoder.

Comment: Doesn't seem to convert perfectly either, get some words converted properly rest are random ascii.

Answer (score 8):

Since Delphi 6, Delphi has included the `EncdDecd` unit, which includes the [DecodeString](http://www.google.com/search?q=DecodeString%20EncdDecd%20site:embarcadero.com) function which decodes the `Input` string containing `base64` text into a `Result` string with actual decoded data (which might be binary):

```
function DecodeString(const Input: string): string;
```

Since Delphi 2009, it also includes the [DecodeBase64](http://www.google.com/search?q=DecodeBase64%20EncdDecd%20site:embarcadero.com) function which decodes the `Input` AnsiString into a binary `Result` of TBytes:

```
function  DecodeBase64(const Input: AnsiString): TBytes;
```

In addition to an [earlier Delphi/PHP base64 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564082/mime-base-64-encoding/3566746#3566746) I gave, I now wrote a small unit test that shows how DecodeString and EncodeString work:

```
unit Base64TestCaseUnit;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, TestFrameWork, Generics.Collections;

{
 base64 test vectors: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648
   BASE64("") = ""
   BASE64("f") = "Zg=="
   BASE64("fo") = "Zm8="
   BASE64("foo") = "Zm9v"
   BASE64("foob") = "Zm9vYg=="
   BASE64("fooba") = "Zm9vYmE="
   BASE64("foobar") = "Zm9vYmFy"
}
const
  Key_ = '';
  Value_ = '';
  Key_f = 'f';
  Value_f = 'Zg==';
  Key_fo = 'fo';
  Value_fo = 'Zm8=';
  Key_foo = 'foo';
  Value_foo = 'Zm9v';
  Key_foob = 'foob';
  Value_foob = 'Zm9vYg==';
  Key_fooba = 'fooba';
  Value_fooba = 'Zm9vYmE=';
  Key_foobar = 'foobar';
  Value_foobar = 'Zm9vYmFy';
// binary test vector
  Key_binary = #1#2#3#4;
  Value_binary = 'AQIDBA==';

type
  TStringStringDictionary = TDictionary<string, string>;
  TBase64TestCase = class(TTestCase)
  strict private
    FBase64VectorsDictionary: TStringStringDictionary;
  strict protected
    procedure DecodeTestOneKey(const ExpectedKey: string); virtual;
    procedure EncodeTestOneKey(const ActualKey: string); virtual;
    property Base64VectorsDictionary: TStringStringDictionary read FBase64VectorsDictionary;
  protected
    procedure SetUp; override;
    procedure TearDown; override;
  published
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_binary;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_f;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_fo;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_foo;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_foob;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_fooba;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_DecodeString_Test_foobar;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_binary;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_f;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_fo;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_foo;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_foob;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_fooba;
    {$IFDEF CLR}[Test]{$ENDIF}
    procedure Base64_EncodeString_Test_foobar;
  end;

implementation

uses
  EncdDecd;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_binary;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_binary);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_f;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_f);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_fo;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_fo);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_foo;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_foo);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_foob;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_foob);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_fooba;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_fooba);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_DecodeString_Test_foobar;
begin
  DecodeTestOneKey(Key_foobar);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.SetUp;
begin
  FBase64VectorsDictionary := TStringStringDictionary.Create();
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_, Value_);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_f, Value_f);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_fo, Value_fo);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_foo, Value_foo);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_foob, Value_foob);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_fooba, Value_fooba);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_foobar, Value_foobar);
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Add(Key_binary, Value_binary);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.TearDown;
begin
  FBase64VectorsDictionary.Free();
  FBase64VectorsDictionary := nil;
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_binary;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_binary);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_f;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_f);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_fo;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_fo);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_foo;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_foo);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_foob;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_foob);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_fooba;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_fooba);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.Base64_EncodeString_Test_foobar;
begin
  EncodeTestOneKey(Key_foobar);
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.DecodeTestOneKey(const ExpectedKey: string);
var
  ActualKey: string;
  ExpectedValue: string;
begin
  ExpectedValue := FBase64VectorsDictionary[ExpectedKey];
  ActualKey := DecodeString(ExpectedValue);
  Self.CheckEquals(ExpectedKey, ActualKey, Format('base64 decode of "%s" should be "%s"', [ExpectedValue, ExpectedKey]));
end;

procedure TBase64TestCase.EncodeTestOneKey(const ActualKey: string);
var
  ActualValue: string;
  ExpectedValue: string;
begin
  ExpectedValue := FBase64VectorsDictionary[ActualKey];
  ActualValue := EncodeString(ActualKey);
  Self.CheckEquals(ExpectedValue, ActualValue, Format('base64 of "%s" should be "%s"', [ActualKey, ExpectedValue]));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTest('', TBase64TestCase.Suite);
end.
```

Comment: Yes; also Indy provides its own Base64 encoder\decoder which is available in all versions of Delphi (Delphi 6 and newer versions).

Comment: @vcl OP wants to avoid using Indy

Comment: @David after trying 3 different things in various Indy versions, and all failing, I have stopped using it too. Too bad, it used to be a nice library.

Comment: @Jeroen Could you possibly clarify your answer to state what `DecodeString` actually does. If it does what I think it does then this answer looks like the best one yet.

Comment: @Jeroen: Indy's encoder/decoder works fine for me.  What kinds of problems are you having with it?

Comment: @Remy: I had trouble with POP3, ICMP and serious version incompatibilities, all in different Delphi/Indy versions. It made me shy of using Indy.

Comment: @David did my example clarify this enough?

Comment: @Jeroen I still don't know what `DecodeString` does and why it's different from `DecodeBase64`.

Comment: Did my edit explain the difference and behaviour well enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a ready-rolled solution try [DIMime](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/mime/history?DokuWiki=e)

Answer (score 1):

```
uses
  Math;

var
  Base64: array[0..63] of AnsiChar = (
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
    'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
    '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/');

function IndexOfBase64(const C: AnsiChar): Integer;
begin
  for Result := Low(Base64) to High(Base64) do
    if Base64[Result] = C then
      EXIT;
  Result := -1;
end;

function DecodeBase64(Value: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  iC, iB: Integer;
  B: array of Integer;
  C: array[0..3] of Integer;
begin
  SetLength(B, Floor(Length(Value) / 4) * 3);

  iC := 1;
  iB := 0;
  while iC <= (Length(Value) - 3) do
  begin
    C[0] := IndexOfBase64(Value[iC]);
    C[1] := IndexOfBase64(Value[iC + 1]);
    C[2] := IndexOfBase64(Value[iC + 2]);
    C[3] := IndexOfBase64(Value[iC + 3]);

    B[iB]     := (C[0] shl 2) or (C[1] shr 4);
    B[iB + 1] := ((C[1] and 15) shl 4) or (C[2] shr 2);
    B[iB + 2] := ((C[2] and 3) shl 6) or C[3];

    Inc(iC, 4);
    Inc(iB, 3);
  end;

  SetLength(B, Length(B) - (Length(B) mod 16));

  for iB := 0 to High(B) do
    Result := Result + Chr(B[iB]);
end;
```